# How to get the "columns" array, which was passed in while initializing the table in Datatables.js, later in the code using the table api?

Tags: jquery, datatables

In jQuery plugin `Datatables.js` after I set the columns like below

```
 var tableApi = $('#example').DataTable({
        columns: [
                  {
                      "title": "Date Of Order2",
                      "name": "DateOfOrder",
                      "data": "DateOfOrder"
                  }, {
                      "title": "Status",
                      "name": "Status",
                      "data": "Status"
                  }, {
                      "title": "Order Number",
                      "name": "OrderNumber",
                      "data": "OrderNumber"
                  }, {
                      "title": "Category",
                      "name": "Category",
                      "data": "Category"
                  }, {
                      "title": "Client Name(s)",
                      "name": "ClientName",
                      "data": "ClientName"
                  }
                ],
        ajax: "objects.txt"
    });
```

How can I use this `tableApi` later in my code to get a hold of the above `columns` array.

`tableApi.columns()` gives a 2D array of the cells (with actual table data). Not the array I need.

I am actually interested in the `"data":` key's values in the above `columns:` array.

```
           columns: [
                      {
                           ...
                           ...
                          "data": "DateOfOrder"
                      }, {
                           ...
                           ...
                          "data": "Status"
                      }, {
                           ...
                           ...
                          "data": "OrderNumber"
                      }, {
                           ...
                           ...
                          "data": "Category"
                      }, {
                           ...
                           ...
                          "data": "ClientName"
                      }
                    ]
```

I tried using columnDefs but no luck there. As `tableApi.columnDefs` is not a member.

It seems like the table api doesn't expose this information which it received while initializing.

Answer (score 0):

Okay I got the answer.

For anybody's future reference it is done by

```
var cols = tableApi.init().columns;
```